# std::timed_mutex::try_lock_for and Windows multithreading

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, mutex

I would like insight on a behavior that I have observed regarding std::timed_mutex::try_lock_for on a Windows Server 2019. Client applications communicates with a server that handles each client on a separate thread. The communication ends with the server updating a file with some statistics. The server does approximately this:

```
std::timed_mutex file_mutex;

void
update_statistics_file()
{
    if (!file_mutex.try_lock_for(5s)) {
        cerr << "Could not obtain lock on file mutex. Not updating statistics file." << endl;
        return;
    }
    boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lock(file_mutex, boost::adopt_lock_t());

    (void)mkdir(directory_name);
    HANDLE win32_handle = CreateFile(file_name, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    if (win32_handle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        return;
    }
    int fd = _open_osfhandle((long)win32_handle, O_RDWR | O_BINARY);
    if (fd == -1) {
        return;
    }
    FILE* stream = _fdopen(fd, "r+b");
    if (stream == NULL) {
        return;
    }

    cerr << "Statistics file opened successfully" << endl;

    // Read from and write to file stream
}
```

The odd behavior happens when I have about 30 client applications running on the same host as the server, and all starting and ending at the same time. The communication is successful for all 30 connections. A few (usually around three) server threads updates the statistics file successfully. The statistics file update takes only a few milliseconds. However the main bulk of the threads ends up waiting for the mutex. One thread gets a lock on the mutex, however it does not reach "Statistics file opened successfully" until the main bulk of the threads has timed out waiting for the mutex. I would expect all threads waiting on the mutex sleeping and that the thread obtaining the mutex lock to get priority and do its task swiftly.

The behavior is much better when the client applications runs on a different host, since the communication over the network make the communication end at a slightly different time points.

It this something that can be blamed on the Windows Server multithreading implementation, or is this related to std::timed_mutex::try_lock_for? Or does the file opening have anything to do with it?

Comment: I'm not sure whether using `boost::lock_guard` for a `std::[timed]mutex` is wise.  I would use `std::lock_guard` instead.  Also (tangential), why not just `fopen`?

Comment: Why are you doing all the expensive filesystem syscalls while holding the lock? They're supposed to be idempotent anyway (right?) so they should probably be outside the locked section